# label or instruction expected at start of line assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I've started learning Assembly and I can't figure out what is the problem. When I try to use the command "nasm assembly.asm -f elf64", it shows this message: label or instruction expected at start of line.

my code is:

```
bits 64
global assembly
assembly:
  mov eax, 777
  ret
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you are assembling that gives the error is exactly what you posted here? This code should be fine, so I can only assume you are assembling different code or maybe the wrong file.

Comment: Not a [mcve].  Copy/pasted that into `foo.asm`, and `nasm -f elf64 foo.asm` silently succeeds for me.  (NASM 2.14.02).  Perhaps you have some non-printable character in your real file?  Look at a hexdump.  Also, don't use `bits 64` - that's implied by `-f elf64`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:   Removing the `:` would not be an error, merely a warning: `warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]`.  "assembly" isn't a valid instruction mnemonic like `loop` or something so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Now it worked! thank u, guys =)